# Using SelectLayerByLocation and GetCount to Populate a new Field using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I'm attempting to create a script which assesses the intersect between a layer "BldgFootprints" and several polygons "FireBoxMap_1"-"FireBoxMap_44". And from this intersects performs a getCount on a particular attribute of the BldgFootprint layer and uses it to populate a newly created field in the FireBoxMap polygon attribute table. Essentially I'm trying to create a count of single family homes within particular fire districts using a buildings database and then adding this count to the fire district attribute table to tell at a glance how many homes are in each district. I am using PyCharm IDE and ArcGIS Pro.

So far I have:

```
import arcpy
try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = (r'L:\ProgrammingPro\FireDepartment.gdb')
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("FireBoxMap*")
    print (fcs)
    lyr = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("B*")
    print (lyr)
    for fc in fcs:
        inFeatures = "fc"
        fieldName1 = "Single"
        fieldName2 = "Multi"
        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, fieldName1, "SHORT", "","","","","","","")
        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures,fieldName2, "SHORT", "","","","","","","")
    bldg_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(b*,r'in_memory\bldg_lyr')
    firebox_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FireBoxMap*,r'in_memory\firebox_lyr')
    firebox_bldg = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(bldg_lyr,'HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN',firebox_lyr*)
```

I have a failed to execute error in the MakeFeatureLayer section and don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange!  Please edit your question to include the specific error that you receive with the above code snippet.  (I assume there's more code below this since it's missing an `except` clause.)  Note: if the * appearing in the last line `(firebox_lyr*)` is in your code and isn't a typo, remove it.  Also the MakeFeatureLayer_management needs to pass a filename and/or path, so replace `b*` with `lyr` and `FireboxMap*` with `inFeatures` or `fc`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this updated code sample based on the comments above. Some general notes: You need to pass a specific feature class or shapefile into MakeFeatureLayer_management, so need to remove the wildcards. Variables, full file paths, or file names within the workspace all work.  Double-check the output of `lyr` as I think it's a list; in the make feature classes I assumed you'd want the first list element.

```
import arcpy
try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = (r'L:\ProgrammingPro\FireDepartment.gdb')
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("FireBoxMap*")  
    print (fcs)
    lyr = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("B*")
    bldg_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr[0],r'in_memory\bldg_lyr') # changed this line
    print (lyr)
    for fc in fcs:
        inFeatures = "fc"
        fieldName1 = "Single"
        fieldName2 = "Multi"
        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, fieldName1, "SHORT", "","","","","","","")
        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures,fieldName2, "SHORT", "","","","","","","")

        firebox_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,r'in_memory\firebox_lyr') # changed this line
        firebox_bldg = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(bldg_lyr,'HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN',firebox_lyr)     # changed this line
```

Comment: This worked! No errors, but I have some follow-up questions, I have 44 separate FireBox polygons. Is this syntax running a separate SelectLayerbyLocation for the single Building layer and each Firebox? Or just the Building Layer and the first listed Firebox?

Comment: As listed, this will do just the first firebox. Are you looking to match each individual firebox (44) to the same number of buildings (44) on a 1:1 basis, or to loop through each combination of firebox and buildings?

Comment: Based on this question and a re-read of your post I moved the three lines into the loop. Each individual firebox (`for fc in fcs`) is evaluated against one single bldg_lyr. You will need to modify if you want to evaluate against multiple building layers.